# How to define an inner product argument in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I would like to make an inner-product symbol for my math paper. I would like it to work along the lines of `\frac{arg1}{arg2}`. Specifically, I would like to make a function, so that I could say

`\inner{arg1}{arg2}`,

and get something that looked like

`\langle arg1, arg2 \rangle`. If someone could guide me through how to do this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: What I do is add `\let\<\langle` and `\let\>\rangle` to my preamble and then use `\<a,b\>` in the document. Alternatively, you could use something like`\def\<#1,#2>{\langle #1,\,#2\rangle}` and then `\<a,b>`.

Answer (score 22):

Using `mathtools` you can make a definition that allows resizing of the brackets when necessary.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\inp}[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1, #2}

\begin{document}

\( \inp{\mathbf u}{\mathbf v} \)

\begin{equation*}
  \inp*{\frac1n\mathbf u}{\frac 2n\mathbf v} =
  \inp[\Big]{\frac1n\mathbf u}{\frac 2n\mathbf v}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

In this version `\inp` just prints standard sized brackets and `\inp*` uses `\left...\right` to scale the brackets to enclose the material.  Often `\inp*` will produce brackets that are too big, and manual scaling can be provided by `\inp[\big]`, `\inp[\Big]`, `\inp[\bigg]`, `\inp[\Bigg]` etc.

Answer (score 13):

```
\newcommand\inner[2]{\langle #1, #2 \rangle}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Does this work to create any function, like these?

Comment: @phatty Yes. You may read section 6.1.1 of  [The Not So Short
Introduction to LATEX 2e](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/lshort-english/lshort.pdf).

Comment: Nte that this has the defect of not being able to scale the fences if you ever need to.

Comment: @daleif You can always add `\left` and `\right` before `\langle` and `\rangle`, respectively, to get automatic scaling

Comment: @Daniel which, of course, is a very bad idea. Too many cases where they scale too much.

Comment: @daleif Realy? I didn't know that. I'll stick to the other answer then.

Comment: @Daniel the one Andrew gives above, is the one I'd recommend,and always use. Then auto scale is just adding a * in those cases that need it.